# High rise API giving a 'No first name' error when adding a person, even though its provided

Tags: curl, highrise

I'm attempting to create a new person using HighRise's API:

```
curl -u xxxxxxx:X -XPOST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <first-name>Test</first-name>
    <last-name>Acct</last-name>
    <title>CEO</title>
    <company-name>Test inc</company-name>
    <contact-data>
        <email-addresses>
            <email-address>
                <address>a@b.com</address>
                <location>Home</location>
            </email-address>
        </email-addresses>
        <phone-numbers>
            <phone-number>
                <number>1111</number>
                <location>Home</location>
            </phone-number>
        </phone-numbers>
    </contact-data>
</person>' 'https://xxxxxx.highrisehq.com/people.xml'
```

However, this gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>First name  is missing. Contacts must have a name</error>
</errors>
```

I'm quite confused, as I seem to be following their API and providing the info as they expect it (as documented [here](https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/people.md)).

Is this a bug in their API, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it requires to add the `Content-Type` header with xml POST request. Add the following with your curl request.

```
-H "Content-Type: application/xml"
```